# Why is (If false return "true") ... returning true?

Tags: php, return-value

Inside the begining of a function I have this:

```
if(false);
{
    return 'TRUE';
}
```

it is returning "TRUE"! Obviously my real use was checking a more useful expression and returning something else. I just changed it to this to elaborate my point.

Why is this happening? Can you not put a return inside an if statement? I do this all the time in other languages.

For example

instead of this:

```
function () {
if(something)
{
//process stuff
}
}
```

which requires wraping everthing inside the function inside an if.

I prefer to do this:

```
function() {
if(!something)
return;
//process stuff
}
```

Is this not OK in PHP... is there a work around?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're just crazy. :)

```
if(false); //   <----- remove semi colon
{
    return 'TRUE';
}
```

should have one less semi-colon.

```
if(false)
{
    return 'TRUE';
}
```

Comment: Wow do I feel like a jackass now. Its been a really long day.. but I should have seen that before posting.

Comment: +1 for spotting a mistake which can easily eat up hours near-instantly. Well, maybe it becomes a habit to look for semicolons when facing this kind of bug...

Comment: if this is supposed to be a [boolean](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), it should read `TRUE`, without the `'`

Comment: @Gordon, its not supposed to be a boolean, I am echoing out what the function returns and I just quickly changed it to "true" so I could visually see if the `if` was returning true.

Comment: On a side note, I always put the opening "{" bracket on the same line as my IF statement. I find it easier to distinguish that it's an if line just by skimming the right-most characters.

Answer (score 8):

You have an extra semicolon after the `if` condition.